# Help with texturing a test model

Tags: texturing, documentation

I made an animated box with the intent of importing it into GZDoom as an MD2 for testing. The problem is that I can't get this whole UV mapping thing down. The MD2 exporter won't let me export the model, saying that it needs at least 1 skin to export. I read the Blender 2.83 documentation on this a few times (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/modeling/meshes/uv/applying_image.html) but the mapping window pane they are displaying doesn't seem to exist in my version of Blender!! I have a picture here of where I'm stuck at: (https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap4KZFMds2L1hGq1cPxTVZPnft8Y?e=bQA8xP). I also have here the .blend file right where I got stuck: (https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap4KZFMds2L1hGkboQxzDy50WN0s?e=85dXcA) .

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: You indicate that there may be a discrepancy between document and software versions. Yet how is anyone to confirm or disconfirm that possibility when you only present the version of the manual you are referencing, but not the version of the software you are using?

Comment: I am using Blender version 2.83 LTS. The link I posted is the one referred to by the main menubar " Help > Manual " . I didn't think that would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not assigned the image texture to the material. That's the reason why it's no shown on the cube.

In the material properties, click the yellow dot right next to *Base Color* and select *Image Texture*. Then click the image icon with a little arrow next to it that just appeared. In the popup select your image. Done.

Alternatively, go to the *Shader Editor*. Add an *Image Texture* node, select the image, and connect the color output of the *Image Texture* node to the *Base Color* input of the *Principled BSDF*.